# Correlators at large $N$ and large $N$ factorization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, ads-cft, large-n

I am having this very basic problem. In e.g Maldacena's AdS/CFT review (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0309246) (page 5), he has defined operators as $\mathcal{O}=N\,{\rm tr}[f(M)]$ for some matrices $M$ and got the connected correlators as $\langle\mathcal{O}\mathcal{O}\rangle_c\sim N^2$ and $\langle\mathcal{O}\mathcal{O}\mathcal{O}\rangle_c\sim N^2$. Whereas in the MAGOO review (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111) (page 14-15 e.g) we see some operators defined as $G$ which is added to the action as $S\rightarrow S+N\sum g_jG_j$ which gives the correlators as $\langle\prod_j G_j\rangle\sim N^{2-n}$. So that three points and higher vanish at large $N$. I thought this one is generic. If so I wanted to understand how is the first conventions/case are different and their difference (has it something to do with connected/disconnected diagram? etc.).

Related to that I wanted to know about large $N$ factorization. For a particular model if I calculate disconnected  diagrams, I see that at large $N$ I indeed get this factorization. I learned that its like WKB in $\hbar\sim 1/N$. But I wanted to feel it more generally in possibly a mathematical+insightful way if possible.

Edit: If it has a long answer please at least let me know which way to think.

Comment: Isn't it just because the definition of $\mathcal O$ includes a factor of $N$? I.e. if we would instead define $\mathcal O = \textrm{tr}[f(M)]$ then  we would get $\langle \mathcal O \mathcal O \rangle \sim N^0$ and $\langle \mathcal O \mathcal O \mathcal O \rangle \sim \frac{1}{N}$, consistent with your other expression.